# Performance testing for Desktop application who uses UDP

Tags: jmeter, udp, performance-testing, desktop-application

Looking for tool to do performance testing for desktop application.

I was trying to use Jmeter for performance testing but since my application uses UDP protocol so i think i cannot use jmeter record and replay functionality.

How can i record and replay desktop application which uses UDP using JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [UDP Request plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UDPRequest/)

> This plugin adds UDP protocol support to JMeter. With this plugin you can load test DNS, NTP, TFTP, Boot servers

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can record and replay only [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) and [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) traffic (both are using [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) protocol as underlying transport) with its [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) therefore you will not be able to record the traffic using JMeter.

So I would recommend capturing raw UDP datagrams using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and building the JMeter test plan by manually adding and populating appropriate UDP Sampler requests. Check out [Load Testing UDP - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-udp-the-ultimate-guide/) article for detailed information.